# How to separate json data from file into collection and objects in C++?

Tags: c++, json, c++11

Hi File contains following json data

```
{
    "data1": {
        "name": "main_window"
    },
    "data2": {
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "data3": {
        "background opacity": "(sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;" 
    }
 }
```

How do we use standard c++ string library to separate out collection and object from above json data. In above data there is 3 collection and 1 object and 3 name value pairs.

Comment: Technically there are *four* objects, three nested inside the first.

Comment: Usw `for`, `while`, `if`, `else`, `find`, `substr`, etc.

Comment: Did you try jsoncpp https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp ? It will give an easier access to JSON data

Comment: If the data you get is as well-formed as in the example, and the strings can't contain embedded double-quote characters or closing braces, and the object nesting is only a single level as in the example, then a simple state-machine and simple looping and appending characters to a string and a `std::map` should be all you need. No need for `find` and `substr`, using them will probably make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ *standard* library does not know anything about JSON. But *Boost* does. You can use [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/property_tree.html), which has a JSON parser included.

Comment: How about separating objects using string substr or find ? @Christian Hackl

Comment: @codeg33k It's possible, but it's a ***lot*** of work. Simple, but still a lot to do, and you're probably not going to be able to handle more advanced variants using only simple tools like `find` and `substr`, for that you need a proper parser similar to what a compiler might use.

Comment: @codeg33k: The format is too complicated, and you will have a hard time handling all corner cases. It will take ages to get it to work and will still fail every once in a while for certain input. You can either take all that trouble or just reuse the wheel which people invented and built for you.

Comment: Well I just want to accomplish to separate to this specific json type data. That's why I was asking. Data that would be passed would be this specific.

Comment: @codeg33k: You mean the data will, for example, *never* contain `"`, and it will be OK for the program to not handle non-simple input? In this case, you may do without a parser. But honestly, the Boost solution is so simple. It allows you to solve your problems with about 5 lines of code. Why complicate your life?

Comment: That would be best solution for sure. But this is only learning task I am doing which has requirement of using only string library.